# Get all puppet class parameters

Tags: puppet

I want to avoid what seems to be a huge amount of duplication that is used in most puppet examples I've seen:

```
class foo(
    String arg1 = '',
    String arg2 = '',
    ...
){
    if arg1 != '' {
        ...
    }
    if arg2...
}
```

To something more pragmatic like

```
class foo(
    String arg1 = '',
    String arg2 = ''
){
    # $@ is like $@ in POSIX shell
    $@.each {|k, v| if k[v] != '' { contain $v } }
}
```

Comment: If the keys aren't important, then shouldn't the argument just be an array and you just use `contain $values` to include all of those named classes? The example looks a bit contrived, it'd be useful to see the real manifest to give a better answer.

Comment: Yeah it seems really unclear what you are trying to achieve here by refactoring boolean conditionals into a lambda iterator due to lack of content.

Comment: @DominicCleal A good example: https://github.com/example42/control-repo/blob/production/site/profile/manifests/base/linux.pp specifically the duplication of the params to the conditionals.

Comment: @MattSchuchard To make it so I don't have to duplicate params to conditionals

Comment: It seems an uncommon example to me, but I've tried to answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @nwmcsween Ok that example cleared up your intentions. You can clean that up a lot with Hiera. I would recommend that. The specific example you linked to is in bad need of a `hiera_include`/ENC and is quite off from best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a construct equivalent to `$@` that I'm aware of, so I'd suggest putting all of the data into a hash instead of separate parameters. There isn't any validation of the parameters being performed so a single parameter with the type `Hash[Enum['network', 'mail', '...'], String]` would be quite equivalent to a number of fixed String parameters, i.e.

```
class foo(
    String $pre_class,
    Hash[Enum['network', 'mail'], String] $classes = {},
){
```

Since you don't even need the keys, using all of the contents of the hash would be enough. `values()` is a [stdlib](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib) function.

```
contain(values($classes))
Class[$pre_class] -> Class[values($classes)]
```

If you needed to remove empty values, then use the [filter() function](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/function.html#filter):

```
$filtered_classes = $classes.filter |$type_name, $class_name| { $class_name != '' }
```

I should add that I don't think the given class is a very typical module. It's a profile module and is designed to be very generic and reusable - probably a more typical locally-written profile module wouldn't be configurable to this extent where class names are given as parameter values, and would have more hard-coded behaviour.